# How can I select the substring beginning with the first index and up to the first comma?

Tags: java, substring, indexof

For example, I have the following string:

```
ABC123, CBA 123, cba.cba
```

How can I select just `ABC123`, emitting anything after the first comma?

For some reason, I have been able to get it to work the reverse way, but not the correct way. \_0.o_/

Here's some source code, even though it's not really relevant because it's not working:

```
private void resultListValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    searchText.setText(resultList.getSelectedValue().substring(resultList.getSelectedValue().indexOf(",")+1).trim());    
}
```

This produces

```
CBA 123, cba.cba
```

SOLUTION

```
private void resultListValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    searchText.setText(resultList.getSelectedValue().substring(0,resultList.getSelectedValue().indexOf(",")));    
}
```

Comment: Use substring(start,end)

Comment: Just do that : "ABC123, CBA 123, cba.cba".split(",")[0]

Comment: @RémyBaron That would create a String array.

Comment: Thanks @MuratK., that was the solution.

Comment: @Susannah Potts : No "ABC123, CBA 123, cba.cba".split(",") is a String Array   but with [0] it's the first element (so a String)-> that's what he wants

Comment: @RémyBaron I didn't see the [0].  Either way, no need to be so condescending and rude.  And as Pshemo pointed out, that is an incredibly inefficient way to get something that could be accomplished with indexOf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use StringBuilder to accomplish this pretty easily.

```
StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder(str);
String target = sb.substring(0,sb.indexOf(","));
```

Comment: I was always taught string manipulation should be done via a StringBuilder.

Comment: Thanks friend! I didn't use the StringBuilder, but this helped me discover the solution!

Comment: "*...string manipulation should be done via a StringBuilder*" but you are not manipulating string, you are creating new one based on old one. Remember that String is immutable so even if you want you can't manipulate it. Finding specific part of string is not manipulation.

Comment: It's the solution I gave, and comments are not the place for extended debate.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could split the string first:

```
String[] parts = string.split(",")
```

And after you could get the firt one

```
String word = parts[0]
```

Comment: I just want to add that this solution would require iterating over entire string just to find one specific part which in this case is placed at its start. `substring`/`indexOf` combination is faster here.

Comment: This solution could be more useful it you need to keep all the values too, they will be in the String Array

Answer (score 1):

**indexOf** will give you the index of first occurrence of the specified substring which is ",".
And **subString** will get part of your String starting at the beginning (zero index) up to the desired position which in your case is the index you get from **indexOf**. Just note that the ending index in EXCLUSIVE which means up to that index but not including that index.

```
String s = "ABC123, CBA 123, cba.cba";
System.out.println(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(",")));
```